# Pytorch wheel not supported on raspberry pi

Tags: pytorch, raspberry-pi, torch, yolov5

I am trying to install pytorch on raspberry pi to use yolov5. (Model is already trained on laptop, only detect.py file has to be run on raspberry pi).
The arch is arm7l

Using following command gives

```
uname -a
```

> Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v7+ #1538 SMP Thu Mar 31 19:38:48 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

Browsing internet the wheel version I have found is [This](https://github.com/sergiovirahonda/PyTorchForRPi.git). Installing this gives unsupported error.

```
pip3 install torch-1.0.0a0+8322165-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple

> ERROR: torch-1.0.0a0+8322165-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.